# SQL Server Management Studio Error : Script failed for UserDefinedFunction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm working on a local and a remote SQL Server instance with SSMS. I create a tiny function like:

```
create function ufnTestFunc ()
returns int
begin
    return 1
end
```

When I try to 'modify' it, or choose 'script function as -> alter', I get an error like:

> Script failed for UserDefinedFunction 'dbo.ufnTestFunc'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> - Syntax error in TextHeader of UserDefinedFunction 'ufnTestFunc'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

This also happens on already existing functions. What may be the reason?

---

**Notes:**

- All the functions work as intended
- I can script the function as 'create' with no problem.
- It's not related with comments, as there are no comments in the test function
- Same happens with different DBs on the remote server

Local Server:
Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) - 10.50.2500.0

Remote Server:
Microsoft SQL Server Web Edition (64-bit) - 10.50.1600.1

SSMS:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    10.50.2500.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                           3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                  2.0.50727.5448
```

Comment: No chance of using something like SQL Profiler?

Comment: Indeed, profiler could give some more info on the issue. But now it appears to be a bug so I would need to find it out by trial&error anyway -) Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok like someone mentioned before, but with a little difference.

The problem is the `AS` keyword. Although the `AS` keyword before the function content is optional, SSMS can't handle functions without it. They work, but make trouble. It's a bug and not mentioned anywhere in the BOL.

I normally use the `AS` keyword, but this time the DB is from a previous coder, who didn't use it. In my test function I also didn't use it to make the function as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sp_helptext N'ufnTestFunc'`

Is there anything in the "comment" section above the function that looks *odd*?

Embedded comments `/* */` can sometimes cause that error.

Example:

```
/* 
    This function does something. 
    /* NOTE: not any useful, though */
    More stuff...
*/
alter function ufnTestFunc ()
returns int
begin
    return 1
end
```

Comment: So, nothing in the text header of this function?

Comment: no, just the function itself. the first line of the create function script I run, is the 'create function' line itself.

Answer (score 0):

--Adding that I received this error and could neither script nor modify the sproc.

The problem was a block comment section inline, inside another block comment.

```
/*  
Example call:  
 Exec [usp_mySproc] @Param = '172777'  /* blah, blah */
 Exec [usp_mySproc] @Param = '172777', @Debug = 1   WITH RECOMPILE   
*/
```

Removed inner comment block and no problem.