# SQL Server Management Studio is not allowing me to Alter views or stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I am installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 of a new PC that I have. When I try to alter a view I get the following error

> Syntax error in TextHeader of View 'ViewName`.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I get this error when I right click on the View > Script View As > Alter to > New Query Editor Window

[image]

Also, when I try to stored procedure, I get the same error listed above

I get this error when I right click on the View > Script Stored Procedure As > Alter to > New Query Editor Window

I tried to use `SP_HELPTEXT 'ViewName'` this will give me the content of the view. But why is the GUI is not working on this PC but working on my work PC?

How can I correct this issue?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I believe you extract the text from `SP_HELPTEXT`, analyze the text to see for any issues with your code.  When you extract the text and paste it in a query window, you should be able to figure out easily the issue.  It may be some multi-line comments not in proper order.  Try to change the SP using modified text and then try these steps!

Comment: Generate the script as Create To, then change the "Create" to "Alter". This should get around that error.

Comment: @WEI_DBA that worked but how can I fix that issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio Error : Script failed for UserDefinedFunction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731038/sql-server-management-studio-error-script-failed-for-userdefinedfunction)

Comment: I'm assuming that you are connecting to a previous version of MSSQL. This might be known bug in SSMS 2016. Not positive.

Comment: indeed it is a bug https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3103831/ssms-2016-16-4-fails-when-attempting-to-alter-modify-a-stored-procedure-syntax-error-in-textheader-of-storedprocedure

Comment: Yes... and just opened 3 days ago.

Comment: Lots of ridiculous bugs being reported with the latest release of SSMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS stopped loading my stored procedures after update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623876/ssms-stopped-loading-my-stored-procedures-after-update)